# Is there a way to detect if string concatenation have been used?

Tags: c#

In our datalayer, I want to discourage the use of string concatenation and make people use parameters instead.

But as far as I know, there is no way to see if a parameter is a concatenated string.

I have no code example to show of detection, since I know of none.

```
var result = db.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " + id);
```

This is the kind of code I'd like to get rid of, either to replace with something like:

```
db.executeQuery($"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = {id}");
```

or

```
db.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = {0}", id);
```

Edit:

The command `executeQuery` is in our datalayer and handles parameters as SqlParameters, with types and values.

So in this case a `SqlParameter` called `@id` with type `int` would be created.

Regarding the `FormattableString`:

```
public T ExecuteObject<T>(FormattableString sql)
{
    return executeSingleRow(sql.Format, sql.GetArguments()).ToType<T>();
}
```

Regarding the `ExecuteQuery`:

```
public int executeNonQuery(string sql, params object[] parameters)
{
    var traceI = Traceadd(sql, parameters);
    if (!open())
        throw new Exception("Error executing query!", lastException);

    try
    {
        command = Connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        sql.SQLFormat(ref command, parameters);
        var res = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Parameters.Clear();

        if (traceI != null)
            traceI.Stop();

        return res;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (traceI != null)
            traceI.Stop();

        throw new DBException(command.CommandText, command.Parameters, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: None of these examples use parameters. It just replaces parts of the strings instead of concatenating them.

Comment: Actually there is no difference regarding sql injection.

Comment: IMO, all 3 cases are the same and should be avoided. The way to go is to use parametrized query, see for example [SqlCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You can try to solve the problem from the *other end*: force DBMS using bind variables, e.g. in case of *Oracle* `alter session set cursor_sharing = force;`  https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/entry/improve_sql_query_performance_by

Comment: The `executeQuery` makes SqlParameters of the parameters that we add.

Comment: @NoLifeKing How would it identify the parameter in the second call? The string format is evaluated before the string is passed to the method.

Comment: If you pass it as a `FormattableString`, you can grab the parameters before it is evaluated.

Comment: @Adwaenyth in any call the concatenation is done before ;-)

Comment: It would really help if you'd show your `executeQuery` method, to avoid all this confusion. At first sight it definitely looks like this would still be just as broken.

Comment: @Sehnsucht: The third one doesn't use string format, so the logic of that call could be implemented if the `executeQuery` is a custom overloaded method that could interpret any `param object[]` as in need for `SqlParameters` and add them.

Comment: (You've now shown `ExecuteObject`, which wasn't mentioned before and appears not to be used, but not `executeSingleRow`. It doesn't help that your code seems to sometimes use conventional names and sometimes not.)

Comment: @NoLifeKing Aside from the subject ; IMO `executeQuery` shouldn't do two different thing ; either transforming some string (or formattablestring) into actual parametrized query or "really" executing the query but not both

Comment: Yeah, the pseudo-code I used at first doesn't apply to the actual datalayer. The actual code base is old and patched around.

Comment: To answer your question, no, there is no way to look at a string in .NET and detect if it is a result of string concatenation.

Comment: @NoLifeKing you last sample show a method named execute**Non**Query

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you. That's the answer I sought. So I'll just have to mark the other functions as deprecated and start fixing the code. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `executeQuery` method only has a parameter of `FormattableString`, then you should be fine already - there's no conversion from `string` to `FormattableString`. For example:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int id = 10;
        ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " + id);
    }

    static void ExecuteQuery(FormattableString query)
    {
    }
}
```

That gives an error:

> Test.cs(8,22): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.FormattableString'

You just need to make sure that you don't have an overload of your method accepting `string`. The result of string concatenation is never a `FormattableString`. Indeed, I would strongly advise that you avoid ever overloading a method to accept `FormattableString` and `string`... there's no point in doing so if you're *not* going to change the behaviour, and if you *are* going to change the behaviour, that could be really confusing.

I'd personally consider changing to use an extension method on `FormattableString` though - something like:

```
public static SqlCommand ToCommand(
    this FormattableString query,
    SqlConnection connection)
{
    // ...
}
```

That way you can separate the command creation from the execution... which means (aside from anything else) that you can then call `ExecuteReader` or `ExecuteNonQuery` without having any extra code yourself.

Comment: This would work perfectly. The reason I have other functions that take the string and object[] is because of legacy code. Thanks.

Comment: @NoLifeKing: See my edited answer for other suggestions, btw.

Comment: I've changed the signatures of all my DB-commands now, to only accept `FormattableString` as parameter, currently rewriting all code that needs attention. Luckily, this was a small project. Not looking forward to the other projects. :) Thanks for the help